# Testing Sanic file Uploads

Tags: aiohttp, sanic

When looking at the [docs](http://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/testing.html) I see a great examples of how you can test a sanic app.

```
# Import the Sanic app, usually created with Sanic(__name__)
from external_server import app

def test_index_returns_200():
    request, response = app.test_client.get('/')
    assert response.status == 200

def test_index_put_not_allowed():
    request, response = app.test_client.put('/')
    assert response.status == 405
```

Now I'm trying to get the testing framework to accept an uploaded photo to the endpoint. The code I have works via:

```
upload_payload = {'image':  open(os.path.join(img_dir, img_name), 'rb')}
request, response = app.test_client.post('/image', file = upload_payload)
```

It gives an error suggesting I cannot pass a file along. Does the testing framework not support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the standard for these sort of things is posting a `data` parameter along. This works just fine:

```
upload_payload = {'image':  open(os.path.join(IMG_DIR, img_name), 'rb')}
request, response = app.test_client.post('/image', data = upload_payload)
```